# Aliases resolved incorrectly in YAML modules?

Tags: perl, yaml

I'm trying to load a "simple" YAML file using Perl:

```
foo: &baz
  dog: cat
  cat: rat
bar:
  <<: *baz
  rat: cheese
```

Using [YAML](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/YAML/lib/YAML.pod), [YAML::XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/YAML-LibYAML/lib/YAML/XS.pod), or [YAML::Syck](https://metacpan.org/pod/YAML::Syck) I'm getting unexpected output from a [test script](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ddb2b11dcc5cb0a92ee0f60b652b8d99):

```
{
  'foo' => {
    'cat' => 'rat',
    'dog' => 'cat'
  },
  'bar' => {
    'rat' => 'cheese',
    '<<' => $VAR1->{'foo'}
  }
}
```

In this case, `{bar}->{dog}` is `undef`.  Running the same input through [YAML Lint](http://www.yamllint.com/) (or even [Ruby's YAML module](https://gist.github.com/exegete46/706daabf8e36577d6e25d52502311f88)), it outputs as expected.

How can I get Perl to parse and output the correct format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That YAML and YAML::Syck do not support the [merge key language-independent type](http://yaml.org/type/merge.html) is logical, as these parsers implement YAML 1.0 and that extension was proposed for YAML 1.1.

The extension is not part of the YAML 1.1 specification, and e.g. libyaml, on which YAML::XS is based, does not support it on its own. Ruby, Python and JavaScrip YAML parsers, implement the merge on top of the libyaml library, something that YAML::XS doesn't seem to do.

As @bart commented, there are some workarounds by traversing the tree after loading: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=813443

Comment: So basically I'd have to fork one of these modules and patch in code for parsing aliases (which appear to be part of YAML 1.2?  Can't say I'm that familiar with reading language specs).

Comment: There are Perl workarounds, for example: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=813443

Comment: If you do start with YAML::XS which is based on libyaml. Alternatively you can preprocess the file with a parser that supports merge by reading the file in and writing it back out. Except from my ruamel.yaml parser for Python that preserves the merge on roundtrip, all other parsers will "unmerge" the mapping and then you can read it into Perl with any of those libraries.

Comment: @bart Can I extend my answer with that, or do you want to post that yourself as an answer?

Comment: @Anthon sure, you can extend your answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Pointed out in the comments and still an issue today but I've found Mike Farah's version of the yq command line tool is a great work-around, https://github.com/mikefarah/yq:

```
cat <EOF > sample.yml
- anchors:
  - &foo
    key1: val1
  - &bar
    key2: val2
- somedict:
    <<: *foo
    <<: *bar
EOF
```

and test with perl:

```
use YAML::XS;
undef $/;
open($f,"yq -p yaml -o json sample.yml | yq -p json -o yaml|");
print YAML::XS::Dump(YAML::XS::LoadFile("sample.yml")); # bad
print YAML::XS::Dump(YAML::XS::Load(<$f>));             # good
```

and the two very different docs that result:

```
---
- anchors:
  - key1: val1
  - &1
    key2: val2
- somedict:
    <<: *1
---
- somedict:
    key1: val1
    key2: val2
```